# Is it wise to put binding in the machine's Web.Config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, settings

I have several websites sharing common services references, and I'd like not to have to update each website's web.config file evertime the services' url change (not that it happens often).
So I put those references in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Web.Config` file.
O'm not confident about how clever that is.

Should I do it another way?

Comment: I think  your fine: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the same references in your general Web.Config in all environments -- such as Development (developers' PC's), Test, Acceptance/Staging and then Production -- you will be fine.

The problem with shared references like this is if you put them in a centralized location, every time you need to add/modify/delete one, you must do it as a separate process (manually?) and it impacts every application.

So personally I don't advocate it. I like to keep applications as independent as possible.